# Adding dashed property to HtmlHelper in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using a Html.TextBoxFor helper in an MVC4 project.  Our web designer used a custom property of "error-type" for his  box that jquery/javascript looks at to determine how an error should be rendered for that textbox.

I tried doing something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeValue, new { error-type="blue" });
```

But C# doesn't like the property name of "error-type".

Is there a way to be able to use the custom property when rendering it through Razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an underscore; the helper will convert attribute names containing underscores to dashes. FYI, I believe this will only work with MVC-3 or later.

An alternate route is to use the overload that accepts an `IDictionary<string, object>` of HTML attributes. That will be both forwards and backwards compatible.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeValue, new Dictionary<string, object>{{"error-type", "blue"}})
```